# Excepción con funciones en MySqli PDO, orientado a objetos

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb, depuración

Acabo de empezar a usar las funciones de php 7  orientadas a objetos (al menos las de mysqli por que se supone que son más seguras).
Sin embargo, cuando cargo la página queda cargado y no me lanza error, y no entiendo por qué. Cuando la paso por la consoa de debugeo ya sí me muestra lo siguiente:

> ```
> Se produjo una excepción.
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
> boolean in /srv/http/Mantis-rebirth/login.php:26 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}   thrown
> ```

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
   <?php

    if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $usuario = stripslashes(trim($_POST['nombre']));
        $pass = stripslashes(trim($_POST['pass']));

        //ciframos la contraseña
        //$coste = ['coste'=>18];
        //$passhash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$coste);
        if (strlen($pass)>= 8) {
                //He seguido la siguiente documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
                //Definimos los parámetros de mysqli, primero estableciendo los parámetros de conexión:
                $nombreserver = "localhost";
                $usuario = "root";
                $contra = "";
                $bd = "mantis";
                $conexion = mysqli_connect($nombreserver, $usuario, $contra, $bd);
            //comprobamos que podemos establecer conexión
           if ($conexion -> connect_error){
            die("No se pudo conectar ".$conexion->connect_error);
           }
           else {
               //Preparamos la consulta
               $consultaprep = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT contrasena FROM jugadores WHERE (nombre = ?) AND (contrasena = ?)");
               //Ligamos los parámetros
               $consultaprep -> bind_param("ss", $usuario, $pass);
               //Ejecutamos la consulta
               $consultaprep ->execute();
               $consulta = $consultaprep -> fetch();

               if(password_verify($pass,$consulta)){
                    echo "Enhorabuana, te has logueado";
               }
               else {
                   die("La contraseña o el nombre no coinciden");
               }
               $consultaprep -> close();
               $conexion -> close();
           }
        }
        else {
            die("La contraseña no cumple los requisitos");
        }
    }
    else {
            die("Mira, te comento, debes introducir los datos, ¿VALE?");
        }
?>
```

Comment: Yo tambien he tenido que lidiar con ese error, suele ser que en la consulta o en el paso de parametros falla algo, para solucionarlo suelo hacer lo siguiente, muestro con un `echo` la consulta, en tu caso, debes poner esto despues del prepare: `echo $consultaprep;` y como le pasas dos parametros, tambien debes hacer un echo de ambos.
`echo $usuario;echo $passhash;`. Una vez tengas los datos prueba a ejecutar la consulta en tu BBDD, seguramente aparezca un error, lo solucionas en el sql y luego lo pasas al código.

Comment: has intentado quitar los espacios entre los `->` ?

Comment: Otra cosa que suelo hacer es dejar el sql a parte es decir, primero haces:
`$sql = SELECT contrasena FROM jugadores WHERE (nombre = ?) AND (contrasena = ?))";` y luego `$consultaprep = $conexion -> prepare($sql);`

Comment: Hay otra forma, pero no sé si sirve en este caso por que tengo un lío.. en el where pudes poner ```contrasena =: passhash``` creo

Comment: Tu query es erronea, tiene un parentesis de mas.

Comment: Edito el códifgo solucionando los errores antes mencionados, pero no me valida el usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta, que al final no era sólo la consulta, sino un lastre de múltiples errores, por ejemplo, que la bd se exportó mal y los varchar 255 me los puso a varchar 25, el nombre de la variable del nick del jugador era igual que el que hacía la conexión a la base de datos... etc. 
El código funcional es este:
https://github.com/RafaelAybar/Mantis-rebirth/tree/pruebas

Answer (score 0):

De todas formas lo suyo seria ponerlo dentro de un Try-Catch y transaccionarlo, para cuando hay varias queries. Este un codigo que usamoos nosotros en Codeigniter, pero que no te costara expolarlo a otro proyecto con otro framework:

```
try {
    $this->BBDD->trans_start();
    $this->BBDD->conn_id->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tabla` "
            . "(campos) "
            . "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $query = $this->bbdd->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $item = array(tus valores);

    $success = $query->execute($item);
    $lastId = $this->esquema0->insert_id();
    $this->bbdd->trans_complete();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $success = False;
    $error = array("typeError" => "Error", "code" => $e->getCode(), "message" => $e->getMessage(), 'trace'=>$e->getTrace());
}
```

De esta manera activas el errmode_exception y si hay un casque debido a PDO lo podras capturar y presentar muy completo.

un Saludo, Cate.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, he observados una anomalia en tu codigo

Esta en la linea `$passhash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$coste);`

Para que lo realizas? Se supone que es la contraseña de un usario ?

Si haces un `echo $passHash` veras que en cada ejecucion cambia el valor.

Viendo la [docu](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) de `bind_param`  en los ejemplos, asignan el valor a las variables despues de `bind_param`, prueba a bajar unas lineas la asignacion de usuario y contraseña